# AWS MQTT Publish from AWS lAMBDA to device

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I am trying to light my LED connected to the device from the data in DynamoDB. The problem is I am able to connect and give subscribe request to the topic but not receiving any data.

1. I have written a lambda function to fetch data from database.
2. Created rule(Topic) and attached the lambda function
3. Included the TOPIC in the policy for subscribe
4. Using AWSIoTPythonSDK i have created a client in the device using certificates

```
// Code works 
// I have given only the part of code from lambda function
// It fetches data from DB
import json
import boto3

def get_multiple_items():
    return table.scan()


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'payload': json.dumps(get_multiple_items()),
        'event':event
    }

// Code from Device
def customCallback(client, userdata, message):
    print("Received a new message: ")
    print(message.payload)
    print("from topic: ")
    print(message.topic)
    print("--------------\n\n")


print("Subscribing Data")

// It is not calling the customCallback function
myClient.subscribe(topic,1,customCallback)
print("Subscribed Data")
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys I have got the solution to publishing data but stuck with another problem, the publish method only publishes to another topic but I want it to publish to a device.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to include time.sleep(0.005) or some short delay after the .subscribe(..) call.

Can you share the console log output here, to better understand your problem?

cheers,
ram